# Python3 [Classes]- Should I create a new variable to store an instance of a class from a user's input, and how?

Tags: python, class, oop, instantiation

First question here on this site. Still in the very early stages of learning programming and trying to wrap my head around some concepts. I am seriously struggling to find an answer to this problem I have encountered :

So, let's take a simple class:

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
```

Now I would like to instantiate that class, from a user's input, and store that instance in a variable, which could be then appended to a list, giving me something like :

```
 list_employees = [emp_1, emp_2, emp_3]
```

Problem is that these variables (emp_1 etc..) don't exist yet. They would have to be created from the input.

I understand how I could do that myself :

```
emp_1 = Employee(input("Enter name: "), int(input("Enter salary: ")))
```

But I'd like this to be done "automatically", if that means anything, so that the user can create an indefinite number of instances.

I don't need this for anything specific, and I could think of ways to go around the issue with dictionaries, but my brain is just struggling conceptually with this "variable creation by the program" idea... I hope I managed to express it clearly and I'd be grateful if anyone could help me with understanding this or explain to me if and how I'm thinking about this wrong!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example do the following

```
employees = []
for _ in range(1,4):
    name = input("Enter name: ")
    salary = int(input("Enter salary: "))
    employees.append(Employee(name, salary))
```

if you want to acces your variables by name try using a dictionary instead of a list to hold your employees

**EDIT**
With dictionary (f strings only after Python 3.6)

```
employees = {}
for i in range(1, 4):
    name = input("Enter name: ")
    salary = int(input("Enter salary: "))
    employees[f'emp_{i}'] = Employee(name, salary)
```

Comment: Right so a dictionary would give me the possibility to "label" my instances, as in, the key would be the equivalent of a variable name, correct?

Comment: Correct, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need an intermediate variable if all you want is to append the new instance to a list:

```
# python 2 / 3 compat
try:
   input = raw_input
except NameError:
   pass


def create_emp():
    # Q&D, would need error handling
    name = input("Enter name")
    salary = int(input("Enter salary"))
    return Employee(name, salary)


def create_emps()
    employees = []
    while True:
        employees.append(create_emp())
        answer = input("add another ? (Y/n)")
        if answer.lower().strip() != "y":
            break
    return employees

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    employees = create_emps()
    print(employees)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this during the instantiation of your object:

```
class Employee():
    objects = []

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary

        Employee.objects.append(self)
```

Comment: In that case wouldn't the list contain objects that are instances of that class? What I would like to do is assign those objects to variables, and then append those variables to the list.

Comment: What you're asking to do will have exactly the same result - adding variables to a list manually also just assigns the objects themselves to the list. Variables are nothing more than labels attached to your objects.

Comment: "Variables are nothing more than labels attached to your objects". Thank you, that's it, it clicked. Then I can just fetch the object from the list with the list and its index... Got it.